# GenericTypeDefinition for type with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I have following code in C#

```
class c<T> { }
class d<T,E> { }
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(c<>).FullName); // works
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(d<>).FullName); // CS0305 Using the generic type d<T, E> requires 2 type parameters
}
```

edit:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(d<int, int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().FullName);
```

I expect:

```
c`1
d`2
```

does what I want, but I don't want to specify any types during compilation.

How to get `GenericTypeDefinition` for type `d`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(d<,>).FullName);
```

Comment: i struggled with this too at first, but the compiler needs that additional info to distinguish between similar named type definitions with a different amount of generic parameters - hence the comma